# Array output for shifting left cell isn't matching the verifier even though my answer seems to be right

Tags: python, arrays

So I've been trying to solve this code. However, running this code, you'd see that the output says I'm getting the wrong answer. What am I doing wrong here? I'm getting the answer they want but the code is still saying I'm wrong.

```
k=3
source = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
def shift_left(source,k):
    length = len(source)
    for first in range(k):
        for second in range(0,length-1):
            source[second] = source[second+1]
        source[length-1] = 0
    print(source)
    return None

shift_left(source,k)

print("///  Test 01: Shift Left k cell  ///")
source = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
returned_value = shift_left(source,3) # This should return [40, 50, 60, 0, 0, 0]
unittest.output_test(returned_value, [40, 50, 60, 0, 0, 0])
```

This is the code I tried. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The only `return` statement in the function is `return None`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
print(source)
return None
```

Try:

```
return source
```

You are only printing out the correct answer, not returning it. You need to return it.

Comment: Ah thank you. That was it. This can be closed.